# How to create MVC3 DropDownListFor using only part of model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm creating a question/answer page that contains multiple object types (radio button, dropdown, check boxes).

```
Id  QuestionText    AnswerId    AnswerText      ObjectType
1   text one        1           Personal        DropDown
1   text two        2           Business        DropDown
2   Text three      3           Direct Deposit  CheckBox
2   text four       4           Some Answer     CheckBox
```

I have a model that contains a list of all questions, answers, and object types.

How can I populate (as an example) the `dropdownlistfor` with only two items out of the list, then populate a group of related checkboxes, then populate a group of related radio buttons?

The `dropdownlistfor` looks to enumerate on a model.

My code which doesn't work:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
   {
      if (Model[i].AdditionalQuestionTypeId == 1)
      {
          @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model[i].AdditionalQuestionId, ((IEnumerable<Curo.Web.InterAcct.Models.AdditionalQuestionAnswerModel>)Model[i].AnswerText)
            .Select(option => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Description),
                Value = option.Id.ToString(),
                Selected = (Model != null) && (option.Id == Model[i].AdditionalQuestionId)
            }), "Choose...")
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not the best idea to clog up your view with a bunch of logic. That is actually not the desired approach of MVC.

Use this logic in your controller and not the View.
Create you options in the controller that you want for the desired scenario and set the options to the `property` on the `Model`. Then your view will simply bind to that `property`.

```
public class MyModel {
    public string MyValue { get; set;}
    public List<SelectListItem>  Options { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult MyAction(){

    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    // populate options here
    model.Options = new List<SelectListItem>();
    return View(model);
}
```

Then your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyValue, m => m.Options)
```

Comment: +1 The view model should represent what the view wants, not what the model / business layer got.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your code, but I think you are almost there.  You need to do the dropdownlistfor statement with an IEnumerable, but your syntax appears to be off:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model[i].AdditionalQuestionId, new SelectList(Model.Answers.Where(f=>**Some code to select what values you want**), "Id", "Description", Model[i].AdditionalQuestionId))
```

It would help to see an error message, but I think it is just syntax at this point.